# Mismatched size on BertForSequenceClassification from Transformers and multiclass problem

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I just trained a BERT model on a Dataset composed by products and labels (departments) for an e-commerce website. It's a multiclass problem. I used BertForSequenceClassification to predict the department for each product. I split it in train and evaluation, I used dataloader from pytorch, and I've got a good score with no overfit.

Now I want to try it on a new Dataset to check how it works on unseen data. But I can't achieve to load the model and apply on the new Dataset. I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertForSequenceClassification:
    size mismatch for classifier.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([59, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([105, 1024]).
    size mismatch for classifier.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([59]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([105]).
```

I see that the problem probably is a mismatch from labels size between both Datasets. I've searched a bit and I've found a recommendation to use `ignore_mismatched_sizes=True` as and argument for `pretrained`. But I keep receiving the same error.

Here is part of my code when trying to predict on unseen data:

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification

# Just right before the actual usage select your hardware
device = torch.device('cuda') # or cpu
model = model.to(device)      # send your model to your hardware



model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("neuralmind/bert-large-portuguese-cased",
                                                      num_labels=len(label_dict),
                                                      output_attentions=False,
                                                      output_hidden_states=False,
                                                      ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)

model.to(device)

model.load_state_dict(torch.load('finetuned_BERT_epoch_2_full-Copy1.model', map_location=torch.device('cuda')))

_, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(dataloader_validation)
accuracy_per_class(predictions, true_vals)
```

Could someone help me how could I deal with it? I don't know what more can I do!

Any help I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 8):

Your new dataset has 105 classes while your model was trained for 59 classes.  As you have already mentioned, you can use [ignore_mismatched_sizes](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained) to load your model. This parameter will load the the embedding and encoding layers of your model, but will randomly initialize the classification head:

```py
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("finetuned_BERT_epoch_2_full-Copy1.model",
                                                      num_labels=105,
                                                      output_attentions=False,
                                                      output_hidden_states=False,
                                                      ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)
```

In case you want to keep the classification layer of the 59 labels and add 46 labels, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158554/fine-tuning-models-classifier-layer-with-new-label/67187807#67187807). Please also note the comments of this answer, because this approach does not provide any meaningful results due to the random initialization for the new labels.

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to specify the exact `num_labels` as you did. And thank you for the reference to another answer, it will help me later.

Comment: @cronoik  "ignore_mismatched_sizes=True" parameters is no more accepted parameter for BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained() . I am trying to find what is the parameter that works now.

Comment: How is this possible though to need the exact num_labels? len(my_dict) and passing the actual length should both work, it's incredible only specifying the int solution works