# How to resolve the mismatch of pre-trained model parameter and current parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm using pre-trained BERT model for NER task([bert-base-NER](https://huggingface.co/dslim/bert-base-NER)) and I need more token categories than the model had(PER,LOC,ORG,MIS,O). Based on that I create my own dataset which include 7 categories, and modified `config.json` like

```
{
  "_num_labels": 13,
  "architectures": [
    "BertForTokenClassification"
  ],
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 768,
  "id2label": {
    "0": "O",
    "1": "B-Time",
    "2": "I-Time",
    "3": "B-User",
    "4": "I-User",
    "5": "B-Process",
    "6": "I-Process",
    "7": "B-Sepr",
    "8": "I-Sepr",
    "9": "B-PID",
    "10": "I-PID",
    "11": "B-Act",
    "12": "I-Act"
  },
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 3072,
  "label2id": {
    "O": 0,
    "B-Time": 1,
    "I-Time": 2,
    "B-User": 3,
    "I-User": 4,
    "B-Process": 5,
    "I-Process": 6,
    "B-Sepr": 7,
    "I-Sepr": 8,
    "B-PID": 9,
    "I-PID": 10,
    "B-Act": 11,
    "I-Act": 12

  },
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-12,
  "max_position_embeddings": 512,
  "model_type": "bert",
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "output_past": true,
  "pad_token_id": 0,
  "type_vocab_size": 2,
  "vocab_size": 28996,
  "use_cache": false
}
```

the parameter `num_labels` was 9
Then model report error, here is the message:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertForNER:
    size mismatch for classifier.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9, 768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([13, 768]).
    size mismatch for classifier.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([13]).
    You may consider adding `ignore_mismatched_sizes=True` in the model `from_pretrained` method.
```

I tried to follow the advice, but if I add `ignore_mismatched_sizes` in model will return unexpected result which only include tag `Act` `PID` `Sepr`.
Seems the problem is in `pytorch_model.bin` idk.
What should I do to make it output my expect result?(To classify token to `O` `Time` `User` `Process` `Sepr` `PID` `Act`)

Comment: You need to finetune your model. The weights will be randomly initialized when you pass `ignore_mismatched_sizes`. You can keep the existing weights when you follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67187807/6664872), but you still need to train the model to learn the new labels (the training should include all labels not just the new ones).

Comment: It's not just the problem that how many labels I put in, the problem is parameters need to be reset but I don't know how.

Comment: You are already resetting the non-matching parameters with `ignore_mismatched_size`.